# Kannel calling sms-service get-url twice

Tags: kannel

I am using GSM MODEM and gateway 1.4.3 to send sms.
I defined sms-service in my config file to catch all messages with keyword 'TT' and call an URL on receiving sunch message.

My problem is that get-url is getting called twice even though message received is small. Here is my config file..

```
group = smsbox

bearerbox-host = 127.0.0.1

sendsms-port = 13013

log-file ="/tmp/smsbox.log"

log-level = 0

global-sender = 123456

group = sendsms-user

username = tester

password = foobar

#dlr-url = "http://192.168.13.67:8084/TestSMSDelReport/DeliveryReport/getDeliveryReport?smsID=?&timestamp=%t&status=%d&number=%p"

concatenation= true

max-messages = 3 

forced-smsc = gsm_modem

group = sms-service

keyword = TT

#keyword-regex = .*

catch-all = yes

max-messages = 0 

get-url = "http://192.168.75.241:8080/InwardMsg/InwardMsg/inwardMessages?phone=%p&text=%a"
text = "You asked nothing and I did it!"
```

Do I have to change any property so that get-url is called only once?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Remove "catch-all = yes". "catch-all = yes" makes kannel catch every message even if message doesn't match the keyword and call get-url.